# Scala Spark - Get String row values from a WrappedArray

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark-sql

I'm writing a Scala script for Spark and I have a "`specialArray`" as following :

```
 specialArray = ...
 specialArray.show(6)
 __________________________ console __________________________________

 specialArray: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_VALUE: array<string>]
 +--------------+
 |        _VALUE|
 +--------------+
 |    [fullForm]|
 |    [fullForm]|
 |    [fullForm]|
 |    [fullForm]|
 |    [fullForm]|
 |    [fullForm]|
 |    [fullForm]|
 +--------------+
 only showing top 6 rows
```

But would like to see the content of those "fullForm" sub-arrays, how would you do this, please ?

Thank you very much in advance!

I have already tried to get the first value in this way :

```
val resultTest = specialArray.map(s => s.toString).toDF().collect()(0)
__________________________ console __________________________________
resultTest: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [[WrappedArray(fullForm)]]
```

So I don't know how to deal with that and I haven't found anything "effective" in thdoc: : https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/WrappedArray.html.

If you have any ideas or you have some questions to ask me, feel free to leave a message, thanks:).

Comment: You just want to see the content inside `_VALUE` or perform some other operation?

Comment: First of all see what there is inside because I actually don't even know the values I have to expect. And then, maybe perform some other operations.

Comment: @Shankar Koirala : I thank you very much for all your answers but it didn't help me since I couldn't have time to work on it again in the meantime, but be sure I will come back to it soon and then I will accept it if necesary ;). Have a nice day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `specialArray` is a dataframe, So to see the schema of dataframe you use `specialArray.printSchema`, Which shows the datatypes inside the dataframe.

If you just want to see the data inside the dataframe you can use

`specialArray.show(6, false)` the parameter `false` is not to truncate while displaying long values.

Next thing you can do is use `select` or `withColumn` to change the `WrappedArray` to the comma-separated (or any separator) `String`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(concat_ws(",", $"_VALUE")).show(false)
df.withColumn("_VALUE", concat_ws(",", $"_VALUE")).show(false)
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for answering first of all ! Finally I tried your solution but it doen't seem to display what I would like to see. Or maybe the content of the array is lot of Strings where it is just  written "fullForm". Indeed, I tried :

Comment: import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    specialArray.printSchema

    specialArray.select(concat_ws(",", $"_VALUE")).show(false)

    specialArray.withColumn("_VALUE", concat_ws(",", $"_VALUE")).show(false)

    specialArray.map(s => s.toString).toDF().collect()(0)(0)

Comment: Here a screenshot of what I did through Spark, it's more clear : link to my image [(photobox.co.uk)](https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=500749019395). Sorry for the multiple edits. Would you have other ideas about what I could still try ? Or do you think the content of the array is a simple String 'fullForm' or 'abbreviation' ?

Comment: can you share the screenshot?

Comment: Yes, of course, here you have the image : <kbd><img src="https://i.imgur.com/IkWl1X0.png"  width="100" height="100"></kbd>

Comment: PS: I tried to display it directly but it doesn't work :/. The direct link to the screenshot is : https://i.imgur.com/IkWl1X0.png

Comment: How did you load the data  and what is specialArray??

Comment: I loaded a TBX file on Internet and I tried to open it through Spark. About specialArray, it is the array I presented in my first message above your answer. It contains a lot of [fullForm], I displayed the console's results in my post. Then I tried your proposed solutions and I got what you could see on the screenshot uploaded on imgur. What do you think about it please ? :)

Comment: Looking at the screenshot the fullForm is itself a value.